# Looking for continuous data patterns, concepts, and pitfalls

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

First I apologize if this is the incorrect place to ask this kind of question.  In that case I'd like to change my question to "Where I should ask this type of question."

Take Facebook's news feed.  It's a continuous feed of data that's broken up into posts, but is there any programming and storage precedent for storage and retrieval of data that isn't so discreetly broken up?  An example of storing data that's continuous and broken up on arbitrary lines that are created by the programmer rather than the data itself.

It could be broken up by size of data, lines of text, etc. and is retrievable chronologically from first line to last and vice versa.

Hope that makes sense and thank you for any insights you may provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [domain driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

I believe that there is always a system, your domain information, which you can use to cut your data.

DDD defines something called aggregates as autonomous entity. Root aggregate in the case of facebook is `user` but now your domain come into count. You can decide that post is also aggregate for you - for example because of scaling. You can later cut posts for arbitrary user by pages or time (today together, this week). This can be later useful in caching. E.g. cache all posts younger than 24 hours as they will probably required more often than those old one year.

Everything depends on your domain, your requirements. Architecture should be also mirror of your domain decisions, e.g. mentioned caching.

Comment: Cool, thanks Martin.  Feel kind of validated as that was the direction I was heading just didn't know it had a name.  DDD.